# Nonsignificant interaction?

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, interpretation

So, consider a model with variables a, b, and the interaction of a and b.  The interaction is not significant.

I understand that you can interpret a as the effect of a when b=0 
and I can recenter and get the effect of a when b equals various other numbers.

Is it wrong to make these interpretations of a at various values of b, when the interaction is not significant, but a is significant depending on what value of b I use.

I will write the model in SAS format since I don't know how to get all the subscripts and such in:

model Y=a b a*b;  then do lsmeans a/ at b=20; lsmeans a/ at b=50 etc.

Or alternatively
b_centered20=b-20;
b_centered50=b-50; *and then;

model y=a b_centered20 a*b_centered20;
model y=a b_centered50 a*b_centered50;

The significance of a changes with the re-centering of b.

Can I interpret the significance of a if the interaction is not significant.

Comment: "*...but a is significant depending on what value of b I use*". What do you mean by this?

Comment: In addition to @mkt 's question, you could clarify this by writing things in a more usual form. Variables usually are called $X$ with subscripts and each has a parameter associated with it so you would have $Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3$. And you should specify what model you mean (I'm guessing it's linear regression).

Comment: I recognize your name so I'm honored to have you respond to my question.  I'm doing a negative binomial rate model, but the question is about interpreting a non-significant interaction regardless of the type of model.  So, the model you have written out is the correct one.